# How to add an ascending number to every 6th item in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to add an ascending number to every 6th item of an array. So far I have this but at the moment it adds an ascending number to every line, not every 6th line. Can someone say how to fix that? Thanks

```
for(var i=0;i<newlist.length;i++){
    newlist[i]=counter + "." + " " + newlist[i];
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Where in your code does the "every 6th line" come into play?  Right now all you're doing is applying the change to *every* line.

Comment: why dont you check to see if the counter is divisible by 6 with no remainder?

Comment: Amy that's what i'm asking how to do...

Answer (score 3):

`i++` increments the index by one, `i += 6` increments the index by 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over 1 to 1 and add a flag that increments on every 6 line iterated, you need another logic:

```
for(var i=0;i<newlist.length;i++){
    newlist[i]=counter + "." + " " + newlist[i];
    if (i%6==0)
       counter++;
}
```

Edit:
If you want to create the line every 6 iteration:

```
for(var i=0;i<newlist.length;i++){
        if (i%6==0)
            newlist[i]=counter + "." + " " + newlist[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in javascript are 0 based so assuming that you want every 6th element to contain the prefix -

```
for(var i=0;i<newlist.length;i++) {
        if ( (i+1) % 6 === 0) {
            newlist[i] = ((i+1)/6) + "." + " " + newlist[i];
        }
}
```